# Check if Component-preload.js was loaded

Tags: sapui5

I am looking for a way within SAPUI5/OpenUI5 to determine if `Component-preload.js` was loaded or if the original controllers and views were loaded.

So far...

- I tried to exploit the namespace of my project by accessing the global JS objects my.namespace.controller, my.namespace.Component, etc. and trying to find differences when `Component-preload.js` was loaded vs. not loaded.
- I tried to use $.sap.getAllDeclaredModules() and see differences when loaded vs. not loaded.
- I tried to capture the onload event of the `Component-preload.js` from within my SAPUI5 code but I found no reliable way to attach my event handler before the loading happens.
- I tried to compile a dummy controller into my `Component-preload.js` that is not really used in the project. But I did not find a way to create any difference between the state when `Component-preload.js` was loaded vs. not loaded.

I am clearly running out of ideas.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Whats the point?

Comment: @Marc: In our dev team we want to make sure that devs are reminded if the Comp-preload.js is active. To do that we want to show a warning msg. On the live system we want to do the opposite: show a warning if the Comp-preload is missing. (This is a non-Fiory solution, so Comp-preload must be actively generated through Grunt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is optimal but a small and simple solution I came up with:

The following function tries to load the Component-preload.js file

```
checkComponentPreloaded: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            sap.ui.require(["com/your/namespace/Component-preload"], (CP) => {
                resolve();
            });
        } catch (e) {
            reject();
        }
    });
}
```

Then somewhere else (e.g. init of your Component.js) you can handle the promise and do stuff (probably set some property in a config/view model):

```
this.checkComponentPreloaded()
    .then(() => { Log.error("Preloaded"); })
    .catch(() => { Log.error("Not preloaded"); });
```

---

Slight catch: If the Component-preload is available but empty it will still tell you it's preloaded.